# Limit the length of a token

Tags: flex-lexer

How to specify an upper limit of a token's length in flex?

E.g. having and identifier consisting of numbers and letters and has to be at most 1024 characters long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,1024}
```

according to what you said. However it's more likely to be

```
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{1,1023}
```

as you normally need identifiers to start with a letter.

But you may find it better to simply enforce the rule in the action. Otherwise the scanner wil simply chop say a 2048-character identifier in half and return both halves as tokens, which isn't really what you want.

1024 is ridiculously high BTW.